# Can Redis do prefix matching?

Tags: redis

Lets say I have a set of cities in the world like so:

```
EUKLOND
EUKMANC
EUKEDIN
EITROME
EITMILA
EITNAPE
EFRPARI
EFRAVIG
EFRBRES
```

Where the first letter is continent, next two are country and the trailing 4 are an abbreviated city name.

I would like to be able to search this set by passing in "E" which would return all the entries or EIT and retrieve all the entries for Italy or EFRPARI and get just the Paris entry.

Is this something I can do with Redis?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally, it's an Auto-Complete scenario.

[Salvatore Sanfilippo (@Antirez)](https://twitter.com/#!/antirez), Redis's author, wrote a [thorough blog post](http://antirez.com/post/autocomplete-with-redis.html) about how to accomplish this.

**UPDATE:** I just saw another great [blog post](http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/11/29/two-ways-of-using-redis-to-build-a-nosql-autocomplete-search-index), that first takes Salvatore's solution and explains it in a clear way, and second offers another solution that is good also for multiple-word phrases.

Comment: Thanks Ofer, I've read this article but I can't seem to work out how the author arrives at: "zrange zset 6 -1". How does he know that he needs to do a 6 -1 slice? If I have a varying number of cities in a European country how do I calculate X in "zrange zset X -1" ?

Comment: First, he queried where is `fo` located by running `zrank zset fo`. He got the answer `5`. Then, he queried to get all items from 6 (5+1) until the end. He runs `zrange zset 6 -1`. When you use negative numbers, it means 'from the end'. -1 means 'last element of the sorted set' (see [redis documentation](http://redis.io/commands/zrange)).

Comment: Yeah this is what I assumed. The from "fo" to "end of list" is not a viable way for me to do this. The data set above was only an example. I can't really afford to return from some arbitrary point all the way up to the end of the set as this is potentially a massive amount of data (sets can hold ~ 4 billion items IRC).

Comment: Antirez talks about this later in his post: "Fortunately stream algorithms can help us. We know that statistically even taking just, for instance, 300 items per prefix, we'll be able to have a very good approximation of the top five items, since if a query is frequent enough, it will eventually win over the other queries."

Comment: Thanks; I think the answer is "no it can't do exactly what I'm after". It's not suitable for me to have it "overrun" the end of the possible matches by just streaming arbitrarily sized chunks from X onward... Though it might be... hmm I'll have a think about it. Cheers.

Comment: You should think of Redis in a different way than a relational database or dedicated search server. It's lightning fast, and you must realize that it's absolutely OK to do repeated queries - it's still much faster than any other thing. For example, getting repeated chunks of 50 every time until you discover you're beyond your range is perfectly OK in Redis. It took me some time to get rid of "classic" habits and thoughts.